# jQuery variables in JSP files

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to use a Jquery function in a jsp file , this function returns a value , i want to use it in the same jsp file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >

function myfunction(){
$(document).ready(function() {

$("select").change(function(){
    var x= document.getElementById("MCategory").value;

});
return x;
});
};

</script>
```

I want to use x in the same jsp file.

Comment: What do you want to do with this variable in jsp?

Comment: assume i want to print it to the console

Comment: which console? IDE console or browser console?

Comment: And remove method declaration i.e. `function myfunction(){`, as `$(document).ready` will run independently if you write it outside function.

Comment: I want to print it to IDE console

Answer (score 1):

`jsp` file is nothing but a `servlet`. If you want the front value to be processed at the server you can:

1.resubmit to same `jsp` with this value as parameter.
2.submit form to a servlet .

and if you don't want to reload page try `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Var x is defined inside the change function!

the scope only allows you to use the variable x inside the change event.

Declare it outside the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like

```
function squared(A)
{
  //some code here.
 var x= A*A
 return x;
}
```

So every time you call the function you call it like

```
var a = squared(8); // 64
```

`a` will be the return value from that function.